# How do I filter more than one property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to filter many properties at once. Right now I'm only able to filter one property. For example, I want to filter by type, location and experience. So let's say I want `type = PART_TIME location = bangalore and experience = less than 2` the view will return back

```
{
  id: 1,
  type: "PART_TIME",
  name: "Akash",
  location: "bangalore",
  experience: 1
},
```

Here's the code below and the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pine-zwt4o?file=/src/Search.js

```
import "./Search.css";

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      filterList: [
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "Part Time",
          value: "PART_TIME"
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          name: "Full Time",
          value: "FULL_TIME"
        },
        {
          id: 13,
          name: "Freelancer",
          value: "FREELANCER"
        },
        {
          id: 14,
          name: "mumbai",
          value: "MUMBAI"
        },
        {
          id: 15,
          name: "feroz",
          value: "FEROZ"
        },
        {
          id: 16,
          name: "experience",
          value: "EXPERIENCE"
        }
      ],
      searchLists: [
        {
          id: 1,
          type: "PART_TIME",
          name: "Akash",
          location: "bangalore",
          experience: 1
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          type: "PART_TIME",
          name: "feroz",
          location: "mumbai",
          experience: 3
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          type: "FULL_TIME",
          name: "Farheen",
          location: "agra",
          experience: 5
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          type: "FREELANCER",
          name: "Raju",
          location: "chennai",
          experience: 6
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          type: "FULL_TIME",
          name: "Asif",
          location: "vegas",
          experience: 7
        }
      ],
      activeFilter: []
    };
  }

  onFilterChange(filter) {
    const { filterList, activeFilter } = this.state;
    if (filter === "ALL") {
      if (activeFilter.length === filterList.length) {
        this.setState({ activeFilter: [] });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          activeFilter: filterList.map((filter) => filter.value)
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (activeFilter.includes(filter)) {
        const filterIndex = activeFilter.indexOf(filter);
        const newFilter = [...activeFilter];
        newFilter.splice(filterIndex, 1);
        this.setState({ activeFilter: newFilter });
      } else {
        this.setState({ activeFilter: [...activeFilter, filter] });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { filterList, activeFilter } = this.state;
    let filteredList;
    if (
      activeFilter.length === 0 ||
      activeFilter.length === filterList.length
    ) {
      filteredList = this.state.searchLists;
    } else {
      filteredList = this.state.searchLists.filter((item) =>
        this.state.activeFilter.includes(item.type)
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="searchContainer">
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="myInput">All</label>
          <input
            id="myInput"
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => this.onFilterChange("ALL")}
            checked={activeFilter.length === filterList.length}
          />
          {this.state.filterList.map((filter) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <label htmlFor={filter.id}>{filter.name}</label>
              <input
                id={filter.id}
                type="checkbox"
                checked={activeFilter.includes(filter.value)}
                onClick={() => this.onFilterChange(filter.value)}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </form>
        <ul style={{ marginLeft: "70px" }}>
          {filteredList.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <li>
                {item.name} -- {item.type}
              </li>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: It seems to show both fulltime and freelancer, isn't this correct ?

Comment: @Axnyff yes the job/type filter works fine but I don't know how to add another filter on top of that for example if I want to part time and location bangalore. I'm not sure how to start

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic approach would be creating a function that takes a list and some arguments for the filter. The example below uses an object in which you can specify what the value of the property should be to get the filtered result.

```js
const searchLists=[{id:1,type:"PART_TIME",name:"Akash",location:"bangalore",experience:1},{id:2,type:"PART_TIME",name:"feroz",location:"mumbai",experience:3},{id:3,type:"FULL_TIME",name:"Farheen",location:"agra",experience:5},{id:4,type:"FREELANCER",name:"Raju",location:"chennai",experience:6},{id:5,type:"FULL_TIME",name:"Asif",location:"vegas",experience:7}];

const filterList = (list, filterArgs) => 
  list.filter(item => 
    Object.entries(filterArgs).every(([prop, value]) => 
      typeof item[prop] === 'number' ?
        item[prop] <= value :
        item[prop] === value
    )
  );
  
const resultsFullTimeSixYearsExperience = filterList(searchLists, {
  type: 'FULL_TIME',
  experience: 6
});

const resultPartTimeMumbai = filterList(searchLists, {
  type: 'PART_TIME',
  location: 'mumbai'
});
  
console.log('Full time with 6 years or less experience', resultsFullTimeSixYearsExperience);
console.log('Part time in mumbai query', resultPartTimeMumbai);
```